# pthread support in R

Tags: multithreading, r, pthreads

I was looking around for a way to run a R function as a separate thread in the background.
As R is written in C , i was hoping that some packages will support threading using pthreads.
So far i haven’t found anything good , some of the packages i tested were broken or implemented some other concepts. 
So my requirement is as simple as running a R script as a separate pthread inside a R console.
How can i run a function or a script as a separate thread.

PS - I am not looking for fork like features.

Thanks
      Vineeth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [R extensions manual](http://www.hep.by/gnu/r-patched/r-exts/R-exts_13.html):

> There is no direct support for the POSIX threads

---

Alternatively, you can use several R process in parallel. In linux you can simply fork a process by running an R script from a terminal and adding `&`, e.g.:

```
Rscript spam.R &
```

If you insist one doing this from within R:

```
system("Rscript spam.R", wait = FALSE)
```

Or you could have a look at the `parallel` package to run R operations in parallel.

---

Given your comments I think you could have a look at the HighPerformance task view. Quoting from that:

> The bigmemory package by Kane and Emerson permits storing large
>   objects such as matrices in memory (as well as via files) and uses
>   external pointer objects to refer to them. This permits transparent
>   access from R without bumping against R's internal memory limits.
>   Several R processes on the same computer can also shared big memory
>   objects.

indicates that the `bigmemory` package might prove interesting in letting multiple R instances access the same data stored in memory. Than you could use forking to create multiple R instances.

Comment: The first 2 suggetions are same as fork or adding a new process. That is not what i need.

Comment: Why not? Please explain your problem more thoroughly.

Comment: I have R console , it has 2 GB of data loaded into main memory. Now i need to run a script on that data which will take a large amount of time. I want that script to be running in background so that i can run similar scripts in parllel. Here forking wont be a good idea as 2 GB of main memory needs to be duplicated or i have to look for shared memory solutions. Threading looks the best for me.

Comment: If you want to save memory, you need to share memory between the workers, if they or processes or threads does not matter I think.

Comment: Threads work in the same memory space of the process , hence no efforts required to share memory there.

Comment: I think does not support directly creating pthreads. Ofcourse, you can interface C code that uses pthreads.

Comment: And what happens if you change any R data in-memory from one of these threads? Stuff will break.

Comment: @Spacedman Defintely, in this case the user needs to take care that this does not happen. For example using a lock. It could also be that the big chunk of data is kept static, and the processes only require read-access to the big chunk of data.